# DIR 880L Flashing power light

Tags: firmware

I recently updated my firmware, I think it was 1.05, for my 880L directly from the router thinking I'd be able to see my second HDD on my WDTV Live.

Not only was I not able to view the second drive, but the power light is in flash/blink mode and nothing I have tried will correct it.

- I have pressed and held the reset for 10-30 seconds.
- I have also held it while pulling the power and plugging it back in.
- I have tried running a static IP on my PC but was not able to access the router.

The last thing I will try is getting the latest firmware on one of the HDDs and seeing if it will automatically pick it up and install.

Should that fail, are there any other suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1):

Based on how long ago the question was asked, this answer may not help the OP - but here is what I just finished doing to fix the same problem. As in original post a failed firmware upgrade left my DIR 880L with a slow blinking orange light and no connections at all.

Steps to fix:

1. download correct firmware using another network http://support.dlink.ca/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-880L#Download
2. power off device
3. hold down reset button (use a pen or similar) while powering on the device
4. set IP address of cable connected PC (LAN port) to 192.168.0.2
5. attempt to browse to 192.168.0.1

at this point I was presented with the linked screen
[DIR880L Emergency Recovery Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeJKg.jpg)

6. Choose the downloaded .bin file

after the router upgraded itself, it not only rebooted properly - it still had my old configuration

Comment: edited with link

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but unfortunately I'm stuck at this stage. I've tried uploading many different versions of firmware from the D-Link site, and the D-Link Router Recovery Mode screen always says "Upgrade successfully!" (sic) but then doesn't have any new functionality. It remains at that page even upon reload. I'd *love* to fix this router.

Comment: I'm probably stating the obvious - but just in case - after the "success" message did you try power cycling the router, and then making sure you aren't seeing a cached page in your browser?

<opinion> I'm not really very impressed with this router overall

Comment: Thanks for your response. I stayed up til 6am (I think that's the latest I've ever stayed up in my life) working on this freaking thing, and I never got passed the Recovery Mode page. Then I slept for a few hours and then called D-Link and spent *another* hour following their instructions to try everything I'd *already* tried, and then they just said "return it to Amazon." UPS is picking it up tomorrow. Such a waste.